# "#200 You do not have sufficient to permissions to perform this action" in facebook graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments

I had integrated the facebook graph Api for posting a comment on a post shared on any company or Fan page.

When user comment anything on the post from the site then firstly its shared on User's wall and its working fine, next it will be displayed as a comment on particular post(Shared on page). But whenever I am trying to post a comment facebook throwing me 
"#200 You do not have sufficient to permissions to perform this action" this error. I can't understand what I am doing wrong. Here is the code that I am using for comment posting.

Array
(
    [78] => 10
    [19913] => 1
    [13] => 60
    [10018] => facebook-php-3.1
    [10015] => access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&from=100002208841973&link=SITE_URL&name=Arjun+Thakur&message=test&scope=publish_actions%2C+offline_access%2C+manage_pages&method=post
    [10002] => https://graph.facebook.com/owner_id_post_id/comments

)

Can anybody help me on this, I really fed up with this. This issue almost waist my 3 days and i tried everything mentioned in the net, but still not working.

A very big big big thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry guys I was doing wrong. I was using wrong access_tokens thats why facebook returning me this error. I had checked my tokens using facebook app tool, after that I able to find the exact issue. 

Otherwise thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your app's privacy settings is public, otherwise make them public.

To change app's privacy settings:

- Go to *Settings*
- Click on *Apps*
- Then change "*App visibility and post audience*" to public.